# JQuery UI spinner disable with checbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-spinner

I am using the: http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner how can I set it so that if the input has attr=disabled it will disable the spinner?

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="text" class="spinner" />

if($checkbox.attr("checked")){
   $input.removeAttr('disabled').spinner();
} else {
   $input.attr('disabled', true).spinner("option", "disabled", true);
}
```

This code give me error: cannot call methods on spinner prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: http://jsbin.com/ojiwas/1/edit

```
$( ".spinner" ).prop('disabled',true);
  $(':checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(':checked').length>0){
      $( ".spinner" ).spinner();
    }else{
      $( ".spinner" ).spinner("destroy").prop('disabled',true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI spinner has [enable](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#method-enable)/[disable](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#method-disable) methods by default, best to leverage those.  Additionally if you want to default a spinner to disabled just set its input to `disabled="disabled"` then feed `this.disabled` to the spinner constructor.  It is safe to feed `this.disabled` to the spinner constructor every time if you use this approach because the `this.disabled` === `true` if `disabled="disabled"` and `this.disabled` === `false` if the `disabled` attribute is not present.

http://jsfiddle.net/A3SL4/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <label for="spinner1">Default Enabled Spinner</label>
            <input class="spinner" id="spinner1"/>
            <input checked="checked" onchange="enableSpinner('spinner1', this.checked);" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="spinner2">Default Disabled Spinner</label>
            <input class="spinner" disabled="disabled" id="spinner2"/>
            <input onchange="enableSpinner('spinner2', this.checked);" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(".spinner").each(function() {
                $(this).spinner({
                    disabled: this.disabled
                });
            });

            function enableSpinner(spinnerId, enable) {
                var spinner = $("#" + spinnerId);
                if (enable) {
                    spinner.spinner("enable");
                } else {
                    spinner.spinner("disable");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set an option of your spinner widget when it is not created. Instead, you could call your spinner with the constructor option `disable` :

```
if($checkbox.attr("checked")){
   $input.removeAttr('disabled').spinner();
} else {
   $input.attr('disabled', true).spinner({
      disabled: true
    });
}
```

Comment: This works although I need to pass `disabled: false` if checked.

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this without re-creating the plugin each time, like storing a cache of the spinner plugin once. Then called enable/disable methods inside of the if?

Comment: Yes, create your spinner element when DOM is ready with the correct state (enable or not): $(document).ready(function(){$input.spinner({disable:false});}); Then use the option way like in your question called in the change callback of your checkbox element